# Remove WooCommerce Archive Products Title Link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress website that is using the WooCommerce plugin.  I'm trying to remove the hyperlink to the individual product page when I call the product archive. I can't seem to figure it out.  If you look at my site, snivo.com, on the homepage the products are listed, but the titles of the products (which are domain names) are links.  That's what I'm trying to remove.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates` and copy **content-product.php** from there.

Next step is to create on folder in `wp-content > themes > your-current-theme` named as **woocommerce**. And in that folder paste above copied file.

After that open **content-product.php** from `wp-content > themes > your-current-theme > woocommerce`.

There will be an `<a>` below .Remove that `<a>` .

There will be an closing `</a>` **above** `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>`.Remove that also.

That's it.You are done.

Let me know if you have any doubt.